# Best design pattern for integrating third-party api or services

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, architecture

I am integrating some outside APIs into a layered application. Like usual layered apps, it has three layers and I am hooking up those APIs into business layer. By "Thrid party API and services", I mean like payment gateways, postcode look ups, etc.

Currently, for each api, I create a service contract interface and api wrappers will inherit the interface class. And this interface will be injected into business classes' constructors and ioc container will resolve this at the entry point of application.

I would like to decouple those api layers with business layers and make them re-usable in other projects as well. My question is that, is there any better way or any design pattern to use with integrating outside services. I do appreciate any link to guides or code snippets.

Comment: here are lots of design patterns with great description, kindly check it and gain your knowledge... http://planetofcoders.com/tag/design-pattern/

Comment: All you need are interface-based realtions/dependencies between layers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each third party API I would create an interface an put this in a separate project. Then I would create a new project for the implementation of each interface.

For example your project structure could look like

```
YourSolution
  ...
  -Company.Interfaces.ThridPartyAPi1
  -Company.Interfaces.ThridPartyAPi2
  -Company.Interfaces.ThridPartyAPi3

  -Company.Services.ThridPartyAPi1
  -Company.Services.ThridPartyAPi2
  -Company.Services.ThridPartyAPi3
  ...
```

This decouples your code from the API code and decouples the API interfaces from API code, which means that it can be easily mocked/stubbed out for testing.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make a pluggable framework for your third-party API services, you might want to look into MEF. This would enable you to create a more agnostic type of service provisioning, meaning that you can swap in/out services from the framework - which might make it easier to integrate current and future external services into your app without having to incur significant refactor costs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx

Comment: Thank u so much. I just check the calculator code sample on that page and I feel like it's a bit not suitable for my situation. MEF is more suitable for extension rather than integration. In my app, business layer is responsible for providing merchant data to paymentgateway api layer. I don't think it can be done with MEF. Or can it?